# git how to merge just the new changes in a single commit into another branch?

Tags: git

While working on a development branch (newstuff) I had a situations where I had to branch a temporary fix (quickfix) from a commit that was one behind my (master) and push it to a server.

That was easy and worked fine, so that server is running the quickfix branch.

My question is how to merge all the changes (newstuff + quickfix) back into master, without running into a merge conflict.

Not sure if I should do a cherry-pick, or a merge, and in which order.

The quickfix changes a handful of lines that have not been altered my current (master) or my current (newstuff) branches, so the actual changes in quickfix will not cause any merge conflict.

A picture helps: my git repo looks like this (aaaaa is the common ancestor)

```
aaaaa
bbbbb --> xxxxx <== quickfix
ccccc  <== master
ddddd
eeeee
fffff
ggggg  <== newstuff
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just merge them in any order

```
# v1
$ git checkout master
$ git merge quickfix
$ git merge newstuff

# v2
$ git checkout master
$ git merge newstuff
$ git merge quickfix
```

Answer (score 0):

In such situations where you want some commits to be added/pushed to the **master**, you may go for cherry-pick.

It will allows you to add **ONLY** that commit which is useful.

AFAIK, you can do the following commands :

- `git checkout master`(Switch from the test/quickfix branch to master branch
- `git cherry-pick <commit ID>` (Pick up only that commit ID which you want to take)
- `git log` (To check that the particular commit ID is cherry-picked or not.

Check this out, it may work. :)